# get amp; symbol using http_build_query

Tags: php, post, curl

I am submitting some data from website1 to website2 using curl.

When I submit data via then on receiving end I get it like

```
Array
(
    [ip] => 112.196.17.54
    [amp;email] => test@test.com
    [amp;user] => test123,
    [amp;type] => point
    [amp;password] => password
)
```

According to me http_build_query() producing wrong results.

#### "ip" field is correct rest are incorrect.

#### Please let me know why it happens.

curl function is given below: http_build_query($config)

```
function registerOnPoints($username ,$password,$email,$ip ,  $time )
{

    $ch = curl_init("http://website2c.com/curl-handler");

    curl_setopt(

    $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);



    $config = array( 'ip' => $ip, 
                     'user' => $username, 
                     'email' => $email,
                     'password'=> $password,
                     'time' =>  $time,
                     'type' => 'point') ;

    # add curl post data                 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($config));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    # execute 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
 
    # retreive status code
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

   if($http_status == '200')
   {
      $response = json_decode($response);

    } else {
       echo $http_status;
    }


   // Close handle
   curl_close($ch);

}
```

If it is php version issue then, clearly speaking I have no permission to change the version of php because only the **curl** function is producing error rest project is completed and working as expected.
Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i guess you could try:

```
http_build_query($config, '', '&');
```

Or alternative:

```
$paramsArr = array();

foreach($config  as $param => $value) {
   $paramsArr[] = "$param=$value";
}

$joined = implode('&', $paramsArr);
//and use
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $joined);
```

Comment: please explain the reason why it happens

Comment: @surinderpal check this note on php.net:: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#102324, might be that's your case..

Comment: I had to use bin2hex on the string to recognize that indeed, two var_dump'ed strings that look absolutely identical in the browser are actually not so internally...